# Reading a setting file on server

Tags: c#, json, web-services, static-files

I am writing a web service which currently needs to read some settings from a json file on server.

```
string allSettingsTxt = File.ReadAllText(settingsPath);
List<MySetting> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MySetting>(allSettingsTxt);
```

I tried giving following for the path

```
string settingPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\MyCurrentDir\setting.json");
```

But this path wont resolve on the actual deployment, I believe it has to be something like `http://servername/settings/setting.json` ??

1. Where can I store such json file
2. what path I should use to access it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve.

I assume you want to get the path of the settings file which is relative to your executable file.

This is what I do often in my own code:

```
var configFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "config.xml");
```

In this case, config.xml is expected to be in the same directory as the .EXE.

So this would be

```
var settingPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"..\MyCurrentDir\setting.json");
```

in your case.

Also see https://dailydotnettips.com/different-ways-of-getting-path/ for some explanations.

Comment: Thanks bunch for the reply! One question, How can I drop my setting file programmatically n the folder where assembly is getting executed? .

Comment: GetExecutingAssembly is giving me this path: "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\xxxxx\\xxxxxx\\assembly\\dl3\\xxxxxxx\\xxxxxxx\\Setting.json"

Comment: Well, ok, there is no own EXE in your case. Sorry, I'm used to using self hosting in a service. You should try other solutions in the mentioned article. Perhaps HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath.

Comment: Thanks, both AppDomainAppPath and Server.MapPath are giving path to my SPA UX react folder, I need location to my web service folder.